# What happened to the aliens in Italy?

Tags: gantz

Gantz usually bring back people after they kill all the aliens, but when Kurono's team sent to Italy (chapter 291) Gantz sent them back to Tokyo even when the aliens were still there. So what happen with the aliens in Italy? Did they go away or what?

I didn't watch the anime, so I might be missing something here, or maybe there's some explanation ahead? I have already finished reading the manga, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: No italy chapter in the anime

Answer (score 1):

It was a global mission, seems like that every team arround the world has a limit time to help in the mission. Kurono's team were out of time and living ones were teleport back.